# How could drag and drop images to markdown mode?

Tags: image, emacs, markdown, org-mode

I use org-mode to manipulate large files and obsidian to handle tiny files along with mobile.

Is it possible to drag local images to markdown file as org-download does to org-mode?

Comment: I suggest you ask this question in the [Emacs Stack Exchange](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions)  community. As you can see, this question is about `markdown-mode`, but you tagged it with \[org-mode\] here perhaps because tag\[markdown-mode\] is unremarkable in the sea of SO.

Comment: Does [this](https://zhangxingong.fun/post/paste-image-from-clipboard) help?